# How to re-enable listbox when removing a specified item from an output listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I am trying to re-enable only the listbox that pertains to the item that has been removed from the output listbox. For example, If I select "Wagon" from Body Type listbox and "Advance" from Package listbox, the listbox named "lstOutPut" displays the following:

[image: Form Capture]

What I want to do is, if I were to remove "SUV", I would only want for Body Type listbox re-enabled and not the rest

Here is my code

```
private void lstBody_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstBody.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        lstOutput.Items.Add(lstBody.SelectedItem);
        lstBody.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
        lstBody.Enabled = false;             
    }
}

private void lstPackage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    if (lstPackage.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        lstOutput.Items.Add(lstPackage.SelectedItem);
        lstPackage.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
        lstPackage.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

And this is what I have for the remove button

```
private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //remove selected item only
    while (lstOutput.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        lstOutput.Items.Remove(lstOutput.SelectedItems[0]);           
    }

    lstBody.Enabled = true;
    lstPackage.Enabled = true;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there would not be duplicates values among the different input listboxes,you could do the following in the `btnRemove_Click` event

```
 var inputListBoxes = new[] { lstPackage, lstBody };
 while (lstOutput.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
 {
   inputListBoxes.First(x => x.Items.Contains(lstOutput.SelectedItems[0])).Enabled = true;
   lstOutput.Items.Remove(lstOutput.SelectedItems[0]);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is exactly what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

For each listbox, enable it if non of its items exist in `lstOutput`:

```
var listBoxes = new ListBox[] {body, package, wheel, accessories};
foreach(var lst in listBoxes)     
   lst.Enabled = !lst.Items.Cast<string>().Any(x => lstOutput.Items.Contains(x));
```